# Converting from String into ISO time format not working

Tags: python

Been trying to set a time range of 15 min between now and 15 minutes before. So far no problem. Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime 

now = datetime.now()
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'

print(type(now),now)
print(type(past15min),past15min)
```

Output:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'> 2022-12-21 17:51:18.233462
<class 'str'> 2022-12-21T17:36:18.233Z
```

Now, the issue is that I need it to be strictly in ISO format that ends with 3 digits + the letter Z at the end. I'm using this as part of another language Elastic DSL. There, I'm using the variable *now* in the beginning timerange, and the variable *past15min* in the end timerange. What happens is that *now* is in datetime format and end in 6 digits. If I try to type cast it into a string, then the calculation in the past15min variable won't work since you can't subtract strings.

```
now = str(datetime.now())
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'

print(type(now),now)
print(type(past15min),past15min)
```

Output:

```
    past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I also tried to first edit the time into its correct format, which turns it into a string automatically, and then convert it into iso format again to I can do the calculation, but I get an error still.

```
now = datetime.now().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
now_to_datetime = datetime(now)
past15min = (now_to_datetime - timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'

print(type(now),now)
print(now_to_datetime)
print(type(past15min),past15min)
```

Output:

```
    now_to_datetime = datetime(now)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do the string formatting after you perform the calculations?

```py
now = datetime.utcnow()
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15))

formatted_now = now.isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z' # '2022-12-21T09:22:34.213Z'
formatted_past15min = past15min.isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z' # '2022-12-21T09:07:34.213Z'
```

You can now send the formatted data to whatever external system you want.

Answer (score 1):

Only format the datetimes into a string before printing.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
past15min = (now - timedelta(minutes=15))

print(type(now),now.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z')
print(type(past15min),past15min.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z')
```